# Maximum number of characters in a wordpress page?

Tags: pages, htaccess

My wordpress page for **All Time Travel Movies from 1896 and on** is 383.000 characters as html

I can no longer edit it in the WP editor, except as html copied out of WP, manually edited and inserted back into the editor.

In the editor it looks like this - and this is all there is: no comments, no nothing. Comments are accessible from the comments part of the editor, but not on the page's editor page. The Visual window does not become WYSIWYG - but it contains the html in white (= invisible), which becomes black when copied into an external editor.

[image: The Visual window does not become WYSIWYG - but it contains the html in white (= invisible)]

Listings on the page (frontend) contain different values - bold, text colour, links, and there are som images with placement and internal links here too.

eg.

`<span style="color: #ff0000;"> 2016 | <a style="color: #ff0000;" href="link to imdb/?ref_=kw_li_tt"><strong>Tell me how I die</strong></a> | 107 min (dir. D.J. Viola) | Data Over Ages</span>`

It can look like this

[image: Simple listing]

No CSS.

The listing out-grew the limitations of a blogpost over the course of 8-9 years, and now seems to be outgrowing a page?

IS the page html text too large for the editor to handle, or what can I do about it?

At some point the collection WILL move house to its own domain, timetravel.film, but I have no time presently for the BIG renovation. And really know very little code beyong som rudimentary html.

NB: I have no problems with any other posts or pages in the WP installations. .htacces is set to max for the hotel - 256MB.

Comment: I don't know what the max limit is on wordpress or even if it has one and I think this would be more of a limit from the mysql data cell type that holds the data. What I would suggest is that you use a custom post type this way you can have all the films listed as posts with a pagination and would be manageable but to where you would not have your current issue but this now means you would need to insert them as post. Might be able to find a way to import them from another format that would work out quicker.

Comment: These links below will help you to get an easier way to add and manage your movie collection as a page is not the correct way to control large data like this:
https://intenseplugin.com/custom-post-types/movies/
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/
https://www.easywebdesigntutorials.com/creating-a-movie-custom-post-type/

Comment: This sounds like an HTML formatting issue. A malformed style attribute could cause the issue you're seeing. Same goes for a missing closing HTML tag. As @Sam mentioned, the text editor's size limit is determined by WP's database configuration. Post content is stored as LONGTEXT which, even in the worst case scenario would hold over 1 gigabyte of text.  Does text show up when you switch to the text editor? (Note that switching between editors can cause its own issue, so don't save the post after switching. This is just for testing). I'd suggest using an HTML validator to check for errors.

Comment: No, I cannot shift to the text editor. The text is in the Visual editor window, but as white text.

I have tried to find a template way to store posts that would show up like the present list, but have had no luck.

Comment: What I would love would be to have single lines of names and years, which would open on HOLD_mouse_over and display all relevant text and posters. But have not found either.

I will look into sam's suggestions. Thanks.